# Changing Value Back To Date After Using Spreadsheet::Read

Tags: perl, spreadsheet

I have at most a cursory knowledge of Perl. I am writing a script at the moment to parse a .xlsx file shared with me, after which my script takes a selection of columns from it to insert into a SQL database.

However, I have a small issue with one column I am trying to use. There's a date in a column in the Excel file, that from what I've read, Excel turns it into a variant date(?), is this correct? The date is in format dd-mm-yyyy. I am using the CPAN library Spreadsheet to parse the file. I need to try and read the date in dd-mm-yyyy string format if possible.

I am parsing the Excel file using the following:

```
my $book = ReadData($file_source_directory . $file);

my @insuranceBookData = Spreadsheet::Read::rows($book->[1]);
```

And this is how I've planned to set up inserting into the database:

```
            if ($i ne 0 ) { #skip headers

                 my %data_chars = (
                     ...
                     event_date           => convertVariantDateToString($insuranceBookData[$i][62])
                     ...
                );

               
                  my $data_chars_ref = \%data_chars;

                #passing hash reference to @data array
                  push(@data, $data_chars_ref);
            }
        }
```

Is there perhaps a library within Perl that I can use in my convertVariantDateToString function to change the variant date back into a string?

Edit: After spending further time on it, I've come up with this to suit my needs :)

```
            if ($i ne 0 ) { #skip
                #print Dumper $insuranceBookData[$i];

                my $eventDate = 'BL' . $i; #Event Date column in excel file

                if ($book->[1]{$eventDate} ne 'Event Date') { #skipping header
                    my @eventDateTemp = split('-', $book->[1]{$eventDate}); # splitting & converting string into mysql date format
                    my $mysql_d = "$eventDateTemp[0]-$eventDateTemp[1]-$eventDateTemp[2]";

                    my %data_chars = (
                        ...
                        event_date      => $mysql_d
                        ...
                    );

              my $data_chars_ref = \%data_chars;

                    #passing hash reference to @data array
                    push(@data, $data_chars_ref);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what format the dates are in?

Comment: It looks like you can ask this module to produce a specific format, see https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::Read#dtfmt.